# Wordpress shortcodes like in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, shortcode

Do you know a way to have wordpress shortcodes like in Orchard CMS?
I need to allow to user to insert multiple columns in text.

Thank you

Comment: The closest equivalent would be tokens, but they are not currently supported in the body part.

Comment: Maybe only regex could be a valid solution for now. Tnx

Comment: What? How would regular expressions help?

Comment: Let user type a text like [col1]I'm in column1[/col1][col2]I'm in column2[/col2] and win

Comment: Tokens already exist and are going to be way easier to use and extend. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/22/future-orchard-part-1-introducing-tokens.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/27/future-orchard-part-2-more-tokens.aspx